# How to monitor performance of web application behind IIS?

Tags: iis, performance

I have web application installed on the IIS 6. Now i would like to check how many requests are coming to it, How much processor - memory - time it takes to process each request.

Is there something that i can do to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Windows Performance monitor, this article should help you understand which counters do you need:

[ASP.NET Performance Monitoring, and When to Alert Administrators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972959.aspx)

A starter guide: [Using the System Monitor (PerfMon) with ASP.NET Applications (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/b4d4d195-2ecb-4728-9348-6f1bfa1a1b63.mspx). It also contains useful links to the articles describing ASP.NET-related performance counters.